# Approximation of Pr(X > a), with X a multivariate normal rv

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, approximation, integral

Let $X = (X_1, ..., X_p)$ a random variable with a $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ distribution.

$$
$$

$$
\Pr(X_1 > a_1, ..., X_p > a_p)  \\ =\int_{a_1}^\infty ... \int_{a_p}^\infty 
(2\pi)^{-p/2} (\det(\Sigma))^{-1/2} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)' \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\right\}
dx_1 ... dx_p
$$

$$
$$

Does it exist an (analytical?) approximation of this multivariate integral?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but to know more about this I would take a look at the references given for the `pmvnorm` function of the [`mvtnorm` R package](http://essrc.hyogo-u.ac.jp/cran/web/packages/mvtnorm/mvtnorm.pdf)